# How to show that $\sum\frac{c_nt^ne^{-t}}{n!}$ converges absolutely?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We know that $\sum_n c_n$ converges absolutely where $c_n$ is complex.

How to show that $$\sum_n\frac{c_nt^ne^{-t}}{n!}$$ converges absolutely on $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried the ratio test of the term $\left|\dfrac{c_n t^ne^{-t}}{n!}\right|$

I get $$\left|\dfrac{t}{n+1}\dfrac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right|$$

Comment: Hint: it's enough to show $|\frac{c_nt^ne^{-t}}{n!}|\leq|c_n|$ for large $n$.

Comment: So I have to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{t^n}{n!}=0$?

Comment: Yes, that will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that $$(n!)^{1/n} > \log n - 1,$$ we have, by the root test, that $$\left|\frac{c_nt^ne^{-t}}{n!}\right|^{1/n} < \frac {|c_n e^{-t}|^{1/n} t} {\log n - 1} \to_{n \to \infty} 0,$$ where $t$ is a real constant and $|c_n|$ is obviously bounded. This means that the series converges absolutely.